# How can I page query database without lost records?

Tags: java, database

We want to programmably copy all records from one table to another periodically.

Now I use `SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 2 OFFSET <offset>` for fetch records.

The table records like below:

```
user_1
user_2
user_3
user_4
user_5
user_6
```

When I fetched the first page (user_1, user_2), then the record "user_2" was be deleted at the source table.

And now I fetched the second page is (user_4, user_5), the third page is (user_6).

This lead to I lost the records "user_3" at the destination table.

And the real source table may be has 1000 000 records, How can I resolve the problem effectively?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: is this is a one time copy or do you need to keep both in sync

Comment: We need compatible with MySQL, SQL Server and Oracle

Comment: No, there is no need keep both in sync. Just keep destination is same as source table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should use an unique index on the source table and use it in an order clause to make sure that the order or the rows is consistent over time. Next you do not use offsets but start after the last element fetched.

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id LIMIT 2;
```

for the first time, and then

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID > last_recieved_id ORDER BY id LIMIT 2;
```

for the next ones.

This will be immune to asynchronous deletions.

---

I you have no unique index but have a non unique one in your table, you can still apply the above solution with a non-strict comparison operator. You will consistently re-get the last rows and it would certainly break with a limit 2, but it could work for reasonable values.

If you have no index - which is known to cause different other problems - the only reliable way is to have one single big select and use the SQL cursor to page.

Comment: Yes, This is a perfect solution if the source table has a unique index and can use it in an order clause. But because we may can not modify source table, and the source table may also has no unique index or constraint

Comment: So can you provide a common solution for this problem?

Comment: Thank @Serge Ballesta for your patience to answer, We are going to use one select sql and cache in local first.